# Specific file creation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a file. As easy as that is, I can't just provide it with a specific path to create the file in, because this project will eventually be deployed and that path is no longer relative (ex. C:\Users\ledie.....).

this is my current project directory
C:\Users\ledia\Desktop\brolv2\brol\Reports

I have a file in my project directory called Reports which I would like to create text files in and write strings in, my main problem is specifying it to write to that specific folder without giving it the exact path.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Is it just as simple as asking the user for a path where they want to put the file? Can you use the user's temp directory (which is a special variable in C#)? Will any of those options work?

Comment: Add the folder to your project (if it already isn't), go to the folder's properties. "Output to Directory" -> Compile always. When you create the files reference them as 'Reports/filename.txt"

Comment: Use the MapPath function

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed your ASP.NET application in for example `C:\App`
and your file is in `C:\App\Data\data.html`

To get the absolute path use this:

```
String path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/data.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use specialfolders here. For example:

```
string relPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string savePath = Path.Combine(relPath, "Reports");
```

The end result is the app would place the file into a folder called Reports in the current users AppData folder. e.g. C:\Users\ledie\AppData\Roaming\Reports Improved code should verify the existence of the folder and create it if necessary.

See this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more paths you can use in this manner.

Comment: does this function support mac's ? i just tested this with my windows 7 and it works, but the person using my program actually uses a Mac, any clue if its the same thing ?

Comment: p.s, this is currently the best solution i've got from the ones provided